# How to use os.walk() in Databricks to calculate directory size in Azure datalake

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, databricks, azure-data-lake

How to use `os.walk` in Databricks to calculate directory size in Azure datalake.
Python version i'm using is 3.

I was Using Recursive method first to get directory size which failed when the file path is deeper inside directory with `OOM` error.

Now I was curious if `os.Walk()` will work or not.

Any snippet would help.

Recursive function code is below: **[This fails when its deeper path, So, I need different solution]**

```
from dbutils import FileInfo
from typing import List

root_path = "/mnt/ADLS/...../..../"

def discover_size(path: str, verbose: bool = True):
  def loop_path(paths: List[FileInfo], accum_size: float):
    if not paths:
      return accum_size
    else:
      head, tail = paths[0], paths[1:]
      if head.size > 0:
        if verbose:
            <some code>
      else:
            <some code>
  return loop_path(dbutils.fs.ls(path), 0.0)

discover_size(root_path, verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this and feedback?

```
# Python
import sys, os
root = "/dbfs/mnt/rawdata/"
path = os.path.join(root, "targetdirectory")
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path,joint(path, name))
```

Or maybe this?

```
# Python
import sys, os
import pandas as pd

mylist = []
    root = '/dbfs/mnt/rawdata/'
    path = os.path.join(root, 'targetdirectory')
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for name in files:
            mylist.append(os.path.join(path, name))

len(mylist)
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)

display(df)

# convert python df to spark df
spark_df = spark.createDataframe(df)
# write df out as table
spark_df.write.csv("/rawdata/final.csv")
```